# After using editEntityRecord to change taxonomy, changes do not appear until toggling tabs. How can I re-render the taxonomy field?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using a script to change a post's taxonomy in the dashboard, but my changes aren't visible until I click the 'Blocks' tab, and then the 'Post' tab.  Can I refresh/re-render the taxonomy area without user input?

This is within a custom post_type, 'contributor', and using a custom taxonomy, 'topic'.

If I make this call

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core' ).editEntityRecord( 'postType', 'contributor', currentPost.id, { 'topic': [ term_id ] } );
```

Nothing visually changes on the page until either I save and reload, or if I toggle to the 'Blocks' tab and back.  The taxonomy value is set appropriately, but there is no visual indication it happened.  Can I re-render this field (it's in the sidebar).

Answer (score 0):

Just after posting I realized I needed to also update the Content field.  When I do that, it changes to the 'Block' tab automatically.  I don't really want that (I wanted the editor on the Post/Contributor sidebar, not the Block sidebar), so after everything has finished I trigger a click on the Contributor button which effectively solves my problem.  I'd still love to know if there is a more elegant way to re-render, but my particular issue is solved.